# Multiplying Two matrices (2x1) and (2x2(

Tags: python, matrix

Hi for my code I have to multiply a point/vector (1,0) by matrix [1.00583, -0.087156], [0.087156, 1.00583]. The result should give me a new point (x,y)
This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1],[0]])
B = np.array([[1.00583, -0.087156], [0.087156, 1.00583]])
test =np.multiply(A, B)
print (test)
```

The result still gives me a (2x2) matrix instead of a (2x1) that i can use as a point. Is there another function or a better way of going about this?

Comment: What answer do you expect to get in matrix notation? I ask because usually you see matrix x column_vector, not column_vector x matrix.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, if you want to do matrix multiplication use [numpy.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) or the `@` operator, e.g. `B@A`.

Also, when you define `A` like

```
A = np.array([[1],[0]])
```

this creates a 2x1 vector (not 1x2). So if you want to multiply the vector `A` with the matrix `B` (2x2) this should be C = B*A, where C will be a 2x1 vector

```
C = B@A
```

Otherwise if you want to multiply A*B and B is still the 2x2 matrix you should define A as a 1x2 vector:

```
A = np.array([1,0])
```

and get a 1x2 result with

```
C = A@B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test =np.matmul(B,A)
```

This should do the trick.